# Proving that a distribution is heavy-tailed iff its excess distribution is heavy-tailed

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, heavy-tailed

Let $F$ be a distribution supported on $[0, \infty)$ that has finite mean $\mu$. The associated excess distribution $F_e$ is defined by
$$
\bar{F}_e(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, & x < 0 \\
\frac{1}{\mu}\int_x^{\infty} \bar{F}(y)\,dy, & x \ge 0
\end{cases},
$$
where $\bar{F}_e = 1 - F_e$. Exercise 4 in Chapter 1 of [*The Fundamentals of Heavy Tails*](https://adamwierman.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/book-05-11.pdf) asks to prove that $F$ is heavy-tailed iff $F_e$ is heavy-tailed.

In the book, a distribution $F$ is considered heavy-tailed if
$$
\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{\bar{F}(x)}{e^{-\lambda x}} = \infty
$$
for all $\lambda > 0$. It is shown that this is equivalent to the condition that the mgf $m_F(t)$ is infinite for all $t > 0$.

My solution is as follows. We have $f_e(x) = -\frac{d}{dx}\bar{F}_e(x) = \frac{1}{\mu}\bar{F}(x)$, so the mgf of $F_e$ is
\begin{align*}
m_{F_e}(t) &= \int_0^{\infty} e^{t x}\frac{1}{\mu}\bar{F}(x)\,dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\mu}\int_0^{\infty} e^{t x}\left(\int_x^{\infty} f(y)\,dy\right)\,dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\mu}\int_0^{\infty} \int_x^{\infty} e^{t x}f(y)\,dy\,dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\mu}\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^y e^{t x}f(y)\,dx\,dy \\
&= \frac{1}{\mu}\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^y e^{t x}\,dx\right)f(y)\,dy \\
&= \frac{1}{\mu}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{t}(e^{t y} - 1)f(y)\,dy \\
&= \frac{1}{\mu t}(m_F(t) - 1).
\end{align*}
It follows that $m_F(t) = \infty$ for all $t > 0$ iff $m_{F_e}(t) = \infty$ for all $t > 0$, which means that $F$ is heavy-tailed iff $F_e$ is heavy-tailed. My solution assumes that $F$ has a density $f$. It also assumes that $-\frac{d}{dx}\bar{F}_e(x) = \frac{1}{\mu}\bar{F}(x)$; I'm not sure about the validity of this when $\bar{F}$ has discontinuities. Is there a way to prove the assertion that doesn't require these two assumptions?

Comment: Since there are a few different definitions that float around for the concept of "heavy tailed", can you please note the definition of the concept you are using up-front.